# Ballistic trajectory with given start, end point and time

Tags: c#, math, unity-game-engine, game-physics

I have a problem with calculating ballistic trajectory of a cannonball with given parameters: start point (Vector3), end point (Vector3) and time (float). I made a script in C# to calculate the ballistic curve, but the problem is, that it does not work with time. How can I calculate the ballistic force to be applied to cannonball and the angle in which it will reach it's target. The equation must be heigth free (hence the cannon should be above or below target). I need only the equation, I can write then the script in C# but if you want to provide some snippets, I will be only glad :)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about asking about a physical formula.

Comment: o_O ? really ... and doctor google couldn't be of assistance with your hm?

Comment: I don't think two `Vector3` provides enough information to calculate a trajectory. There are an infinite number of possible ballistic curves which could intersect 2 points in 3d space.

Comment: the problem is, I am math-antitalent, I found some relevant stuff, like compute the time of impact and stuff, but I cannot combine it to one equation with those data given

Comment: I will be glad if the cannonball will fly on a slightly curved trajectory, I also tried with Bezier, but they failed me, if there was difference in height, also I tried spherical lerp, but that overshoot the target and then the cannonball turned back to reach its target, which looked...let's just say it, moronic

Comment: public class BallBallistics : MonoBehaviour {

 public Vector3 start;
 public Vector3 end;
 public float time;
 private float startTime;

 void Start() {
  startTime = Time.time;
 }

 void Update() {
  Vector3 center = (start + end) * 0.5F;
  center -= new Vector3(0, 1, 0);
  Vector3 startCenter = start - center;
  Vector3 endCenter = end - center;
  float fracComplete = (Time.time - startTime) / time;
  transform.position = Vector3.Slerp(startCenter, endCenter, fracComplete);
  transform.position += center;
 }
}
this was my (moronic one) trial

Comment: @LászlóCitrusNagy Check out the answer by "tbkn" here: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/248788/calculating-ball-trajectory-in-full-3d-world.html Been using this in my game to assign velocities to `rigidbody.velocity`, works well.

Comment: Chris, thank you very much, can you write it as answer, so I can approve you?

Comment: How is your cannonball controlled? By Unity's physics or by your code?

Comment: This has been asked many times by folks who understood neither the math, physics, nor numerical methods.  I've answered it several times: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22865822/move-an-object-based-on-acceleration/22867161#22867161.   I think an SO search would have gotten you an answer quickly.

Comment: @LászlóCitrusNagy Hey, we once have this problem, we couldn't figure out exactly Unity's equation, it seems to use air resistance, so we ended up having a small difference, despite our knowledge in physics. So we saw 3 possibilities: 1 - not use Unity's physics and having a script to dictate the ball position over time, or create a program to sample hundreds of thousands of shots and numerically create the equation of those shots (2), or use the samples as a "table" in memory to query for information about the path. Surprisingly enough number 3 worked well for us.

Comment: jesus, I can't imagine the 3rd way of doing it. Isn't it resource consuming, hence I must do it for mobile devices. Nonetheless I've managed to solve my problem, I am eager to know how did you computed that, if you would kindly show me :)